# How to save and retrieve a List<Map> with Get Storage

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am trying to persist a simple `List<Map<String,dynamic>>` with GetStorage.

The documentation says:

> When to use GetStorage:
>
> - simple Maps storage.
> - cache of http requests
> - storage of simple user information.
> - simple and persistent state
> - storage any situation you currently use sharedPreferences.

So, I did not encoded/decoded to json String.

In the end, getting error

```
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>?' in type cast
```

Here is my code, and error is thrown at `box.read()` method:

```
  final box = GetStorage();
  var payments = <Payment>[].obs;

  Future<void> savePaymentsToDB() async {
    var paymentsAsMap = payments.map((payment) => payment.toJson()).toList();
    await box.write('payments', paymentsAsMap);
  }

  void getPaymentsFromDB() {
    var result = box.read<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>('payments');
    
    if (result != null) {
      payments =
          result.map((payment) => Payment.fromJson(payment)).toList().obs;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode `paymentsAsMap` to json string. The `toJson` method on your model, only coverts that model to json object (key,value pair). To store that in shared preferences or `getStorage` you should convert that json object to string.

```
import 'dart:covert';

// Storing data
...
var paymentsAsMap = payments.map((payment) => payment.toJson()).toList();
String jsonString = jsonEncode(paymentsAsMap);
await box.write('payments', jsonString);

// fetching data
var result = box.read('payments');
dynamic jsonData = jsonDecode(result);
payments = jsonData.map((payment) => Payment.fromJson(payment)).toList().obs;
```

Comment: I tried your solution. now I get error: Class 'List<dynamic>' has no instance getter 'obs'.
Receiver: Instance(length:1) of '_GrowableList'
Tried calling: obs

Comment: Ok, I just defined List instead of dynamic as: List jsonData = jsonDecode(result);

Comment: Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'toMap'.

//basketAsMap = basketList.map((basket) => basket.toMap()).toList();